# extracting frames from a video using opencv and python

Tags: python, opencv, video, frames

I used this code.

```
import cv2

vc = cv2.VideoCapture('test2.mp4')
c=1

if vc.isOpened():
    rval , frame = vc.read()

else:
    rval=False
    print("hello")

while rval:
    rval, frame = vc.read()
    cv2.imwrite(str(c) + '.jpg',frame)
    c = c + 1
    cv2.waitKey(1)

vc.release()
```

It prints out hello on screen, which means vc.isOpened() didn't called.
I don't understand what seems to be the problem, there is no error.

Comment: you're probably missing the needed drivers

Comment: What kind of  drivers?

Answer (score 0):

It's not problem with the code. The `vc` object is not properly assigned. That's why `vc.isOpened()` getting `False`. If you try the whole code with python interpreter you can check the value of `vc`. Your `vc.isOpened()` it's hold `False` value that's why it's go in the `else` condition and print the `hello`. And because of the failure of initialization it's can't read the and `rval` also getting the `False` value. So the `while` loop didn't execute.

Here i displayed a small demonstration of web cam reading and it's values.

```
In [1]: import cv2
In [2]: a = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
In [3]: a.isOpened()
Out[3]: True
In [6]: ret,frame = a.read()
In [7]: ret
Out[7]: True
```

So you have to check the location of video initialization or your video capturing object. `vc = cv2.VideoCapture('test2.mp4')`

Comment: what is the `0` argument in your VideoCapture ?

Comment: @sumit Usually `0` belongs to the webcam in your machine. If you connected multiple it's go further.